# Number of submodules of $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2-a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modules

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M=\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2-a)$ be a $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module.
I want to prove:

> 1. $M$ has exactly 2 submodules if $a$ is negative.
> 2. $M$ has exactly 3 submodules if $a$ is zero.
> 3. $M$ has exactly 4 submodules if $a$ is positive.

I know that $0$ and $M$ are two submodules for all cases, so that solves the first problem. But I'm not sure what the others are.
Is it just $(X)$ in case 2 and $(X+\sqrt{a})$ and $(X-\sqrt{a})$ in case 3?
Also, how would I prove that there aren't any other submodules in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't solve the first problem. You should prove that there are no other submodules.

Anyway, the $\mathbb R[X]$-submodules of $M$ are in fact the ideals of $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2-a)$.
If $a<0$, then $X^2-a$ is irreducible, so $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2-a)$ is a field.
If $a>0$, then $X^2-a=(X-\sqrt a)(X+\sqrt a)$, and use the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) to see that $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2-a)\simeq\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ which is a ring with four ideals.
For $a=0$ the only proper ideal of $\mathbb R[X]$ containing $(X^2)$ is $(X)$.

Comment: What does being a field for $a<0$ mean in the context of this problem?

Comment: @Bob1993 That it has exactly two ideals.

Comment: And are submodules of a module always ideals of the module?

Comment: @Bob1993 in general there is not even a notion of ideal for  a module, so in general no. But yes for the the R-submodules of R/I for any ringg R and ideal I.

Comment: @Bob1993 No. The modules don't have ideals, but in this case it has because it is also a ring. (In general, the $R$-submodules of $R/I$ are exactly the ideals of $R/I$, where $R$ a commutative ring.)

Comment: Great, thanks alot (also to @quid)